# read dictionaries from one file and create an excel (data frame)l from panda using python

Tags: python

i have an input file like below with multpile rows of dictionaries where the key columns remains same:

```
{'TABSCHEMA': 'OP', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 9, 'COLNAME': 'ACD'}
    {'TABSCHEMA': 'OP', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 8, 'COLNAME': 'ACD1'}
     {'TABSCHEMA': 'OPE', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 8, 'COLNAME': 'AC_CD'}
     {'TABSCHEMA': 'OPEW', 'TABNAME': 'T2', 'COLNO': 7, 'COLNAME': 'AC_ID'}
```

and i want to convert it to data frame like below:

```
Expected O/p:
    TABSCHEMA   TABNAME COLNO   COLNAME
0   OP  T1  8   ACD
1   OP  T1  9   ACD1
2   OPE T1  8   ACC_D
3   OPEW T2 7   AC_ID
```

```
SQL used:
import pandas as pd
def compare(File1,File2):
    with open(File1,'r') as f:
        d=set(f.readlines())
    with open(File2,'r') as f:
        e=set(f.readlines())
    with open('pandastry1.txt','w') as f:
        for line in list(e-d):
            dict_count = len(line)
            print(dict_count)
            df = pd.DataFrame(line[0], index=[0])
            print(df)
   
compare('OPd.txt','OPER.txt')
```

Seems like some issue with query,. Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
            ...
            df = pd.DataFrame(eval(line))
            ...
```

instead of `df = pd.DataFrame(line[0], index=[0])`.

For reading the full file into a dataframe you could do:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(eval(line) for line in file.readlines())
```

(Replace `input.txt` with your file name.)

**EDIT**:
When I paste this

```
{'TABSCHEMA': 'OP', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 9, 'COLNAME': 'ACD'}
    {'TABSCHEMA': 'OP', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 8, 'COLNAME': 'ACD1'}
     {'TABSCHEMA': 'OPE', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 8, 'COLNAME': 'AC_CD'}
     {'TABSCHEMA': 'OPEW', 'TABNAME': 'T2', 'COLNO': 7, 'COLNAME': 'AC_ID'}
```

into a file named `input.txt` and then run

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(eval(line) for line in file.readlines())
print(df)
```

I get

```
  TABSCHEMA TABNAME  COLNO COLNAME
0        OP      T1      9     ACD
1        OP      T1      8    ACD1
2       OPE      T1      8   AC_CD
3      OPEW      T2      7   AC_ID
```

If you want to write a dataframe to excel then use [.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel("input.xlsx")
```

Comment: yes, i am using the command ibm_db.fetch_assoc to fetch data from db2 and writing into a txt file and then i comparing it with old dile and getting their differences and pasting it in new file.

Comment: <ipython-input-4-1d4c47756c9b> in compare(File1, File2)
     11     with open('pandastry1.txt','w') as f:
     12         for line in list(e-d):
---> 13             df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(eval(line) for line in f.readlines())
     14             print(df)
     15 

UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: @rose Two points: (1) You open the file with option `'w'` -> `f` is not readable, `'w'` is for writeable. (2) If you want to replace that part of the code then you should use `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(eval(line))` because otherwise you're trying to read the file twice. Use the first part of the answer. Actually it's a bit unclear to me what you are attempting to do here.

Comment: i am readingtwo text files which has rows of dictionaries. comparing them and finding the difference and printing in third one. so this third one in want in excel file

Comment: i have updated my input file. can you help me getting all the values?

Comment: @rose: See my edit. But your question is not clear. What is the issue: (1) _Getting all the values_ -> see edit (which is essentially a part of what I had posted before). (2) The function `compare`: _Seems like some issue with query._ -> What does that mean? Sorry, but I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237449/discussion-between-rose-and-timus).

Comment: @rose Sorry, I'm at work and the chat page is blocked ...

Answer (score 0):

please check the following solution.

[image]

[image]

Hope this is what you looking for.

```
ss = [{'TABSCHEMA': 'OP', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 9, 'COLNAME': 'ACD'},
 {'TABSCHEMA': 'OPE', 'TABNAME': 'T1', 'COLNO': 8, 'COLNAME': 'AC_CD'},
 {'TABSCHEMA': 'OPEW', 'TABNAME': 'T2', 'COLNO': 7, 'COLNAME': 'AC_ID'}]

import json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(ss)
df.to_excel(‘excel_filename.xlsx’)
```

After updating input:

[image]

Comment: i get this error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: i have updated my input file. can you help me getting all the values?

Comment: Rose after updating the data, I got the above output, hope thats helpfull